# Cover EXCEPTION in the catch block while using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, development-environment

Function to be tested:

```java
public void deleteFile(File file)  {
            
            try {
                Files.delete(file.toPath()) ;
                    
                log.info("Csv file deleted from system succesfully after processing the data");
                    
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                
            }           
}
```

Test code:

```java
@Test
void testExceptionDuringDeletingFile() {
          
      helper=mock(Helper.class);
      
     
      //String bucket ="bucket"; 
      //String key = "key"; 
      File file = new File("");
      
      doThrow(IOException.class).when(helper).deleteFile(file);
      
      Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class,()->helper.deleteFile(file));
}
```

But I am getting the following exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Checked exception is
> invalid for this method! Invalid: java.io.IOException     at
> com.lululemon.product.ap.reprocess.producer.HelperTests.testExceptionDuringDeletingFile(HelperTests.java:191)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `deleteFile()` method doesn't throw the `IOException`. You `catch` it in your method implementation and do something with it.

And, your mocked `Helper` class instance really can't throw `IOException` from the `deleteFile()` method because the real `deleteFile()` method doesn't.

Throw the `IOException` from your method and you won't get the error.

deleteFile method:

```java
public void deleteFile(File file) throws IOException {
    try {
        Files.delete(file.toPath());
        log.info("Csv file deleted from system successfully after processing the data");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Couldn't delete file. Try again!");
    }
}
```

Test method:

```java
@Test
void testExceptionDuringDeletingFile() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("");
        
    Helper helper = mock(Helper.class);
    doThrow(IOException.class).when(helper).deleteFile(file);

    Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> helper.deleteFile(file));
}
```